# set checkbox checked if value same vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm displaying a list of menus in a table and looping with v-for, i want to set checkbox is checked if "id" from data menus same with "id_menu" from grupMenu,  anyone has the same problem, please share it how i can solved, I'm realy new in Vue, thank's for helping,

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    menus: [{
        id: 1,
        name_menu: "Setting",
        parent: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name_menu: "Users",
        parent: 1
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name_menu: "Menu",
        parent: 1
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name_menu: "Role",
        parent: 1
      },
    ],
    grupMenu: [{
        id: 1,
        id_user_group: 1,
        id_menu: 1,
        role: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        id_user_group: 1,
        id_menu: 2,
        role: 0
      },
    ]
  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">Menu</th>
        <th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Previlege</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="">
        <th class="text-center">Insert</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <tr v-for="menu in menus" :key="menu.id">

        <td v-if="menu.parent == 0" style="color:blue">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <!-- <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked"> -->
          <b class="ml-2">{{menu.name_menu}}</b>
        </td>
        <td v-else>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ml-5"> -- {{menu.name_menu}}
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <input type="checkbox">
        </td>


        <!-- </div> -->

      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

here in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/setiawan9/aLyfkcwp/11/)

Comment: _"checked if "id" from data menus same with "id_menu" from grupMenu"_  from **which** `grupMenu`?

Comment: sorry my english not good, yes how to looping data from grupMenu in v-for loop menus, and check it if "id" same with "id_menu" checkbox is checked

Comment: Where is the `v-for` looping over `grupMenu`?

Comment: Are you saying if `grupMenu` contains items with `id_menu=1` and `id_menu=2`, the checkboxes for menu items `1` and `2` should be checked?

Comment: nested v-for in menus, i was try but menu showing multiple list :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the checkbox checked for each entry in `menu` whose `id` appears as a `menu_id` in `grupMenu`.

So write a method like this:

```
isInGrupMenu(id) {
    return this.grupMenu.some((item) => item.id_menu === id);
}
```

and bind it to the `checked` attribute of each checkbox:

```
      <input type="checkbox" :checked="isInGrupMenu(menu.id)">
```

Comment: thank's for help, but just one menu checked, i wan't all menu is checked if "id" same with "id_menu" from grupMenu, update https://jsfiddle.net/setiawan9/aLyfkcwp/22/